# Why javascript Function.caller nequal to function this

Tags: javascript

```
    function T()
    {
        var t = this;
        function Hello()
        {
            alert(arguments.callee.caller == t);//false
            alert(Hello.caller == t);   //false
            //this is a Object
            //but caller just a Function.
            //How?
        }

        Hello();
    };
    T();
```

//-------------------- So,i work code: but i don't like the "property(this)".so...i need like caller Object.How coding?

```
function property(owner)
{
    var that = this;
    this.def = function (name, setFunction, getFunction)
    {
        Object.defineProperty(owner, name, { set: setFunction, get: getFunction });
        return that;
    };
    this.propg = function (name, value)
    {
        Object.defineProperty(owner, name,
        {
            set: function (value)
            {
                ErrorLog(name + "并没有实现属性设置器。");
            }
            , get: function ()
            {
                return value;
            }
        });
        return that;
    };
    this.prop = function (name, value)
    {
        var fieldValue = value;
        Object.defineProperty(owner, name,
        {
            set: function (value)
            {
                fieldValue = value;
            }
            , get: function ()
            {
                return fieldValue;
            }
        });
        return that;
    };
    return that;
}

//#endregion


using('Sofire.Data', function ()
{
    DataColumn = function (columnName, displayText)
    {
        var displayTextChanged = new EventObject();

        property(this)
        .def('DisplayTextChanged'
            , function (value) { displayTextChanged.Add(value); }
            , function () { return displayTextChanged; })
        .propg('ColumnName', columnName)
        .def('DisplayText'
            , function (value)
            {
                displayText = value;
                displayTextChanged.Raise();
            }
            , function () { return displayText; });

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`T` is a FunctionDeclaration, while `t` is the current `ActivationObject` produced when T's ExecutionContext was entered.

You will need to use `arguments.callee.caller == T` in order to get `true`.

Comment: Oh, that's why!But,how get the caller instance?!

Comment: em, you just did - `this` - that *is* the instance